# Dudas con el tamaño de un array de estructuras - ( Uso de sizeof() )

Tags: c++, sizeof

Estaba intentandando obtener el tamaño de este array y "aparentemente" lo he hecho, pero tengo dudas al recpecto.

Este es el código:

```
struct myStruct
{
    string name;
    int min;
    int max;
};

myStruct array[] = {
{"Pepe",        128,   136 },
{"Juan",         70,   100 },
{"Pedro",        50,    60 },
{"Maria Jose",  110,   120 },
{"Bartolo",     145,   180 }
};


int main()
{
   cout<< "Total bytes =" <<  sizeof(array)<< endl;
   cout<< "Bytes Struct=" <<  sizeof(*array)<< endl;
   cout << sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)<< endl;


  unsigned int size=sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);

   for(unsigned int i=0; i<size; i++)
    cout << array[i].name <<" "<< array[i].min <<" "<< array[i].max << endl;    

  return 0;
}
```

Si la siguente afirmación es correcta:

```
sizeof(myStruct) = sizeof(*array) =  sizeof(string) + 2*sizeof(int)
```

donde

```
sizeof(myStruct) = sizeof(*array) = 40

sizeof(string) = 32

2*sizeof(int) = 8
```

¿Cómo es posible que yo pueda poner cualquier string del tamaño que yo quiera y sin embargo el tamaño total en bytes de la variable "array" no varia?
Es decir:

```
sizeof(array) = constante
```

Además me gustaría saber si exiten otros métodos de conseguir el tamaño de este array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Cómo es posible que yo pueda poner cualquier string del tamaño que yo quiera y sin embargo el tamaño total en bytes de la variable "array" no varia?

`sizeof` es una función que se evalúa en tiempo de compilación. Es decir, cuando tu escribes `sizeof(char*)` en el binario correspondiente esa instrucción se sustituye por un número (por ejemplo 4 en 32 bits). Que la función se evalúe en tiempo de compilación tiene ciertas implicaciones... una de ellas es que `sizeof` únicamente puede calcular elementos conocidos en tiempo de compilación y esto excluye, como es normal, a la memoria dinámica.

Por otro lado tenemos que la clase `std::string` hace uso de memoria dinámica para adaptarse a la cadena que debe almacenar en cada momento.

Su estructura interna (muy simplificada) podría ser así:

```
class string
{
  char* ptr;
  unsigned int max_length;
};
```

Es decir, básicamente necesita un puntero y un entero para saber cuántos caracteres puedo almacenar. Nota que en este caso `std::string` ocuparía unos 8 bytes (en 32 bits) y ese tamaño sería independiente del número de caracteres gestionados por el objeto en cuestión ya que esos caracteres se almacenan en la memoria dinámica... que es invisible para el operador `sizeof`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación @eferion. Ahora lo comprendo perfectamente. Un Saludo!!